# How do I know if a BigDecimal failed to parse?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

I'm importing data from a csv, I need to cast some values to BigDecimal, and raise an error if they can't be parsed..

From testing, BigDecimal("invalid number") returns a BigDecimal of 0. This would be ok, but kind of messy, except a valid value is 0...

Float("invalid number") acts differently and throws an exception...

My current solution is:

```
class String
  def to_bd
    begin
      Float(self)
    rescue
      raise "Unable to parse: #{self}"
    end
    BigDecimal(self)
  end
end
```

Am I totally missing something?

Comment: I agree with you, this is wacky and inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

in simple case you can use RegExp

```
'123.4' =~ /^[+-]{0,1}\d+\.{0,1}\d*$/
=> 0
```

Comment: that wasn't really my question, i can think of several ways to validate it, but why does BigDecimal not act like the other types when parsing strings

Comment: from documentation: "The initial value, as a String. Spaces are ignored, unrecognized characters terminate the value". So, its a feature

Comment: @aaz come on, why not acknowledge that it's a bald-faced inconsistency? BigDecimal.new can have that behavior, sure. But why doesn't BigDecimal("blah") raise an ArgumentError to match the behavior of Integer and Float?

Comment: @ms-ati I agree, it seems inconsistent behavior.

Comment: This regex was helpful -- but it seems so strange to have to build a regex to check for a valid parse of a decimal. C# has Decimal.TryParse which returns a boolean. Very straightforward.

Comment: you might also want to consider changing `\d*`to `\d+`. The following code validates: `123."=~ /^[+-]{0,1}\d+\.{0,1}\d*$/`

Answer (score 1):

I came across this inconsistent behavior today.

One approach:

```
def StrictDecimal(arg)
  Float(arg)
  BigDecimal(arg)
end
```

Or a more robust version:

```
def StrictDecimal(value)
  if value.is_a?(Float)
    fail ArgumentError, "innacurate float for StrictDecimal(): #{amount}"
  end
  Float(value)
  BigDecimal(value)
rescue TypeError
  fail ArgumentError, "invalid value for StrictDecimal(): #{amount}"
end
```