# BigDecimal('a8') casts to BigDecimal('0'), why? And how to avoid it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal

I am wondering why when one initializes a BigDecimal with a string it is casted to `BigDecimal('0')` instead of throwing an error:

```
[2] pry(main)> BigDecimal('8')
=> #<BigDecimal:1b1c6e0,'0.8E1',9(18)>
[3] pry(main)> BigDecimal('a8')
=> #<BigDecimal:1ba6e30,'0.0',9(9)>    #<---- Cast here
```

Also I'm interested in knowing a way to make the constructor throw an error instead.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789028/how-do-i-know-if-a-bigdecimal-failed-to-parse) can help

Comment: Thanks! So there is really no built-in way to do it, weird...